# Asp.net MVC 4 date Input Hiding Oldest Days

Tags: html, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want hide oldest date in date input. How to do this ?

Model:

```
 Public Property OrderDate As Date
```

View

```
@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.OrderDate, New With {.placeholder = "Set Date"})
```

Html Output

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Order Date must be a date." data-val-required="Order Date is Required" id="OrderDate" name="OrderDate" type="date" value="01/01/0001">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it [HTML5 min and max](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) attr. For example,

```
<input name="somedate" type="date" min="2013-12-25">
```

In your example

```
<input name="somedate" type="date" min='@DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()'>
```

Comment: changed editorfor to textboxfor and added your property. now its works fine ! thank you